# Rendering Text and Banner in the same header row, DynamicJasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Is there a way to render Text and ImageBanner in the same Header row?

I tried doing the following:

```
.addAutoText("kjasdlkf",
            AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
            ReportGeneratorConstants.TITLE_CELL_WIDTH, style)
.addFirstPageImageBanner(getPropertyDir() + File.separator
            + REPORTING_FOLDER + File.separator + PDF_EXPORT_FOLDER 
            + File.separator + LOGO_FOLDER_NAME + File.separator 
            + SUFFIX, 197, 60, ImageBanner.Alignment.Left);
```

But Its rendering the data in multiple lines:

[image]

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it by overriding **CustomLayoutManager** class.

overrided applyImageBannersToBandLocal method to display image logo and custom-text in the same band.

JRDesignBand headerband = (JRDesignBand) getDesign().getPageHeader();

applyImageBannersToBand()

```
   image.setX(xPosition);
   image.setY(0);
```